# RestController return CompletableFuture<List>

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I try to create rest controller which return all products. I want to use CompletableFuture to return list with product.

I have async request to spring data

```
@Async
@Query("select product from Product product")
CompletableFuture<List<Product>> findAllAsync();
```

and controller

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(path = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
CompletableFuture<List<ProductData>> loadAllProducts2(){

    return this.products.findAllAsync()
            .thenApplyAsync(Collection::stream)
            .thenApplyAsync(s -> s.map(Product::data))
            .thenApplyAsync(s -> s.collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

ProgramData is simple DTO:

```
public final  class ProductData {

    private final String name;
    private final String label;

    public ProductData(String name, String label) {
        this.name = name;
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

Spring return nothing, in log output is :

o.s.b.a.e.mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping     : Did not find handler method for [/products]

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: Don't you have to annotate your controller with `@Controller` so Spring knows that it has to pick it up and look for `@RequestMapping` on it?

Comment: Controller  has @RestController

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm looking in a wrong direction, but I don't see that annotation in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed target directory and It did work.